# Plugin for tags for bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using this one http://sproutsocial.github.io/inputosaurus-text/

But i also want to ask any suggestions for other plugins that can be used and easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

It is easy to understand and had a lot of options. You can easily get its values as an array, string or object.